# Call a parameterized Oracle query from ADODB in Classic ASP

Tags: oracle, asp-classic, named-parameters

I’m currently working on a classic ASP project talking to an Oracle database.  I’m trying to find a way to safely call an Oracle PL/SQL script and passing parameters with ADO.  The currently solution builds the SQL script by hand with embedded variables like this:

```
strSQL = "SELECT field1, etc FROM my_table WHERE (field = '" & filter_value & "')"
```

This, of course, is ugly and insecure, and open to abuse.

The code that I have so far (purloined from various non classic asp based web sites) looks like this:

```
dim strSQL, oConn, oCommand, oParam
set oConn = server.createobject("ADODB.Connection")
oConn.Open myConnString

strSQL = "SELECT field1, etc FROM my_table WHERE (field = :filter_field)"

dim oFilteredList
set oFilteredList = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
oFilteredList.ActiveConnection = oConn
oFilteredList.CommandText = strSQL
oFilteredList.CommandType = adCmdText
oFilteredList.NamedParameters = True

set oParam = oFilteredList.CreateParameter("filter_field", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, filter_value)
oFilteredList.Parameters.Append oParam

set rsResults = oFilteredList.Execute
```

This causes the error “Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided”

What is the correct method of calling Oracle / PL/SQL with named parameters from ADO?  I need to use named parameters because the actual SQL code is somewhat more complex, and different parameters are used multiple times throughout the SQL command.

Comment: Try commenting the line with NamedParameters = True and see if that helps.

Comment: are you using Option Explicit and have you included some kind of adovbs.inc file for your "ad" constants?

Comment: Yep, I've tried both with and without the NamedParameters property, and I am including adovbs.inc.  I always use option explicit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you have `filter_value` defined? If it's not declared as a String or if you've assigned a string longer than 10 characters (as you've indicated when creating the parameter), you'll have issues with that.

Additionally (and partly for my own reference), ***named parameters are not supported via OraOLEDB*** (i.e. ADODB).

See [Oracle® Provider for OLE DB Developer's Guide 11g Release 1 (11.1)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28431/using.htm#sthref143) or follow the "Command Parameters" heading link on any of the [previous versions](http://www.oracle.com/technology/docs/tech/windows/ole_db/index.html) (8iR3, 9i, 9iR2, 10g, 10gR2):

> **Command Parameters**
>
> When using Oracle ANSI SQL, parameters
>   in the command text are preceded by a
>   colon. In ODBC SQL, parameters are
>   indicated by a question mark (?).
>
> OraOLEDB supports input, output, and
>   input and output parameters for PL/SQL
>   stored procedures and stored
>   functions. OraOLEDB supports input
>   parameters for SQL statements.
>
> "**Note**: OraOLEDB supports only
>   positional binding."

That said, this should have no bearing on your query when using OraOLEDB:

```
oFilteredList.NamedParameters = True
```

I've had success running queries exactly as the rest of your example shows though on Oracle 10gR2.

You don't show your connection string, so I must assume it to be valid. Behavior can differ depending on options there, so here's what I successfully use:

```
`"Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=TNSNAMES_ENTRY;User ID=XXXX;Password=YYYY;DistribTx=0;"`
```