# adding data to oracle database in vb6

Tags: oracle, vb6

I have a problem adding data oracle database,it's show me this message(" https://ufile.io/lzpuj ") Run-time ORA-00904:"EMPCODE": invalid identifier.
This is Cody:

```
Dim connEmp As ADODB.Connection
Dim rsEmp As ADODB.Recordset

Private Sub Command1_Click()
   Set rsEmp = New ADODB.Recordset
   rsEmp.Open "select * from tablebooks where empcode = '" & Text1.Text & "'", 
   connEmp, adOpenKeyset, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
   If rsEmp.RecordCount <> 0 Then
      MsgBox " ! åÐÇ ÇáßÊÇÈ ãæÌæÏ ÈÇáÝÚá "
      rsEmp.Close
      Set rsEmp = Nothing
      Exit Sub
   Else
      Set rsEmp = New ADODB.Recordset
      rsEmp.Open "select * from tablebooks where empcode = '" & Text1.Text & "'", 
      connEmp, adOpenKeyset, adLockPessimistic, adCmdText
      rsEmp.AddNew

      rsEmp!Book_no = Val(Trim(Text1.Text))
      rsEmp!Book_name = Trim(Text2.Text)
      rsEmp!Author_name = Trim(Text10.Text)
      rsEmp!Edition_no = Val(Trim(Text3.Text))
      rsEmp!Publisher_place = Trim(Text11.Text)
      rsEmp!Part_no = Val(Trim(Text5.Text))
      rsEmp!Book_cost = Trim(Text6.Text)
      rsEmp!Place_book = Trim(Text7.Text)
      rsEmp!Note = Trim(Text9.Text)

      rsEmp!Date_publishing = DTPicker1.Value
      rsEmp!Subject = Trim(Combo4.Text)
      rsEmp!State = Trim(Combo4.Text)
      rsEmp.Update
      connEmp.Execute "commit"
      rsEmp.Close
      Set rsEmp = Nothing
      Label11.Visible = True
      Label11 = " ! ÊãÊ ÇáÅÖÇÝÉ ÈäÌÇÍ "
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like `tablebooks` doesn't have a column called `empcode`. (Or, it was created with double-quoted column names as something like `"empcode"` or `"empCode"` - if so, you have to refer to it exactly the same way including case and double quotes.)

Comment: Yeah, I believe your table it's looking at doesn't have it.  Also as some friendly advice, this code is very subject to SQL injection hacks.  I recommend using the parameters collection to provide the value of Text1.Text in case someone gets sneaky.

Comment: This will be crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Besides, link https://ufile.io/lzpuj doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure `empcode` is exactly the right column name.

Then fix your code. You have two big issues:

1. It's crazy-vulnerable to Sql Injection attacks.
2. It tries to re-open the same command on the same connection in the ELSE block for no reason.

The exact fix for #1 depends on which provider you are using (Ole vs Odbc), but this link might help:

> [Call a parameterized Oracle query from ADODB in Classic ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135117/call-a-parameterized-oracle-query-from-adodb-in-classic-asp)

For #2, this is somewhat better:

```vb
Dim connEmp As ADODB.Connection
Dim rsEmp As ADODB.Recordset

Private Sub Command1_Click()
   Set rsEmp = New ADODB.Recordset
   'TODO: Use parameterized query here!
   rsEmp.Open "select * from tablebooks where empcode = @empcode '" & Text1.Text & "'", 
   connEmp, adOpenKeyset, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
   If rsEmp.RecordCount <> 0 Then
      MsgBox " ! åÐÇ ÇáßÊÇÈ ãæÌæÏ ÈÇáÝÚá "
      rsEmp.Close
      Set rsEmp = Nothing
      Exit Sub
   End If

   rsEmp.AddNew

   rsEmp!Book_no = Val(Trim(Text1.Text))
   rsEmp!Book_name = Trim(Text2.Text)
   rsEmp!Author_name = Trim(Text10.Text)
   rsEmp!Edition_no = Val(Trim(Text3.Text))
   rsEmp!Publisher_place = Trim(Text11.Text)
   rsEmp!Part_no = Val(Trim(Text5.Text))
   rsEmp!Book_cost = Trim(Text6.Text)
   rsEmp!Place_book = Trim(Text7.Text)
   rsEmp!Note = Trim(Text9.Text)

   rsEmp!Date_publishing = DTPicker1.Value
   rsEmp!Subject = Trim(Combo4.Text)
   rsEmp!State = Trim(Combo4.Text)

   rsEmp.Update
   connEmp.Execute "commit"
   rsEmp.Close
   Set rsEmp = Nothing

   Label11.Visible = True
   Label11 = " ! ÊãÊ ÇáÅÖÇÝÉ ÈäÌÇÍ "
End Sub
```